# java.lang.ClassCastException error

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Hi I'm practicing Java oracle database connection with Eclipse.

Below is my code:

```
package connection;

import java.sql.* ;  // for standard JDBC programs
import java.math.* ; //

public class Connection {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        try {
               Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
               System.out.println("Error: unable to load driver class!");
               System.exit(1);
            }

        String URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:C##AVIVI/avivi9694@localhost:1521:oracleavivi";
        Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
```

Below is the "ERROR":

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection cannot be cast to connection.Connection
    at connection.Connection.main(Connection.java:18)
```

I imported all the "jar" file from "jre7'-"lib"folder into my project(I'm a newbie,so didnt quite sure which jar I need so I imported them all,don't know if this will affect the connection or not)

Answer (score 2):

`Connection` is ambiguous (for you, not for the compiler) here as this is the name of your *main* class:

```
     Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
     //^^^^^^^^         ^^^^^^^^^^
     //   connection.Connection, not java.sql.Connection
```

Either rename your class, or use the fully qualified <strike>class</strike> interface name:

```
     java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
```

Comment: There is no need for the cast itself; `DriverManager` already returns `java.sql.Connection`.

Comment: @Mark Thank you for pointing that out. I've let the cast in my original answer because it was already there in OP's code. But you're right, this is useless. I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Rename your Class to e.g. MyFirstOracleTest (done in eclipse by refactor->rename)